# Jquery mobile + edit in place

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, jquery-mobile

Hello this may be a little clean and green.

The current stack I am using is:

- phonegap cordova
- jquery mobile

and I am making a TODO app for IOS

the app works fine,

```
 <ul id="todo_list" data-role="listview" data-autodividers="false" data-filter="true" data-theme="d">
    <li id="'+i+'"><a href="#" data-transition="slideup"><span style="white-space:normal;">'+todo+'</span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

however what I would like to implement is edit on click, like jeditable. when the user click on the

```
<li>
```

element instead of popping a textbox.

Comment: What would you like to happen when button + is clicked?

Comment: for now its the usual, a popup comes up and the user types in anything he wants too like whatsapp. however I was wondering if there were any framework which offered editing since what I am building is just another TODO app, was hoping that this would help increase functionality and increase user adoption.